# Decoding of 16bit gray image encoded with FFV1

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I have a problem with decoding of gray images encoded with FFV1 codec.
I successfully encode 16 bit gray image (with *avcodec_receive_packet(...)* function) and save *AvPacket* data to file. Then I read this data from file and try to decode (with *avcodec_decode_video2* or *avcodec_send_packet/avcodec_receive_frame*) with no success:

- when I try to decode packet with *avcodec_decode_video2* function I get an error *"Access violation occurred, unable to write location 0x0000000000000000"*.
- when I try to decode packet with *avcodec_send_packet/avcodec_receive_frame* functions I get an error *"chroma shift parameters 7 0 are invalid"*.

I compared packets after encoding and before decoding and all fields and values seems to be the same. I even try to decode packet just after *avcodec_receive_packet* (encoding function), however with the same error.

I use the 4.0 version of ffmpeg and the program is based on *decode_video.c* and *encode_video.c* examples.
When I use containers (eg. avi) to support read/write encoded images from file (based on *demuxing_decoding.c* and *muxing.c examples*) I successfully encode and decode frames with FFV1. However I cannot use containers, because I want to encode frames with different resolutions and mix few video sources together. Additionally the compression level is significantly lower (falls from 2.9 to 2.2) for few hundred of images, what is also very surprising.

So my question is how to correctly save/read (from binary file not container) and prepare AVPacker for decoding with FFV1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The decoding code:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#define INBUF_SIZE 4096
#define FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE 64

uint8_t endcode[4];
AVCodecContext *c, c2;
AVCodec *codec;
int i, ret, x, y;
AVFrame *frame;
AVPacket *pkt, *pkt_temp;

FILE *encodedVideoFile;
AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
uint8_t *video_dst_data[4] = { NULL };
int      video_dst_linesize[4];
int imageSize;
uint8_t inbuf[INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
/* flush the encoder */
    frame = NULL;
    encode();
    /* add sequence end code to have a real MPEG file */
    //fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), encodedVideoFile);
    fclose(encodedVideoFile);
    avcodec_free_context(&c);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
}

void initDecoding(const char *filename)
{
    /* set end of buffer to 0 (this ensures that no overreading happens for damaged MPEG streams) */
    memset(inbuf + INBUF_SIZE, 0, AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
    /* find the MPEG-1 video decoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_FFV1);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 1280;
    c->height = 484;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base.den = 1;
    c->time_base.num = 10;
    c->bits_per_raw_sample = 16;

    c->framerate.den = 10;
    c->framerate.num = 1;

    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY16;

    //Version of FFV1 codec
    c->level = 3;

    /* Init the decoders, with or without reference counting */
    av_dict_set(&opts, "refcounted_frames", 0 ? "1" : "0", 0);
    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, &opts)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = av_image_alloc(video_dst_data, video_dst_linesize,
        c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, 4);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw video buffer\n");
    }

    encodedVideoFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!encodedVideoFile) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* make sure the frame data is writable */
    ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        exit(1);
}

void closeDecoding()
{
    fclose(encodedVideoFile);
    av_parser_close(parser);
    avcodec_free_context(&c);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
}

void decodePacket()
{
    size_t data_size;
    int *got_frame = 0;

    read_packt_from_file(pkt, encodedVideoFile);        

    ret = av_frame_is_writable(frame);

    //First decoding function
    /*ret = avcodec_decode_video2(c, frame, got_frame, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error decoding video frame (%s)\n");

    }*/

    ret = avcodec_send_packet(c, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a packet for decoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(c, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during decoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("saving frame %3d\n", c->frame_number);

        fflush(stdout);

    }

}

size_t read_packt_from_file(AVPacket *packet, FILE *file)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    int size;
    uint8_t * data;
    //av_packet_from_data
    ret = fread(packet, sizeof(AVPacket), 1, file);
    size = packet->size;
    data = new uint8_t[size];
    ret = fread(data, size, 1, file);
    av_new_packet(packet, size);
    av_packet_from_data(packet, data, size);

    return ret;
}
//To write encoded AVPacket
size_t write_packt_to_file(AVPacket *packet, FILE *file)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    ret = fwrite(packet, sizeof(AVPacket), 1, file);
    ret = fwrite(packet->data, packet->size, 1, file);
    if (packet->buf) {
        fwrite(packet->buf->data, packet->buf->size, 1, file);
    }
    fflush(file);
    return ret;
}
```